# How can I fit a GLM using R's glm() evaluated at specific values (e.g. median)?

Tags: r, glm

I would like to fit a generalized linear model in R, using `glm()`. More precisely, it's a `nb.glm()`. Apparently, coefficients fitted in R packages that deal with generalized linear models are all evaluated at mean values *of the other variables*. Is there a way to evaluate coefficients holding the values of other variables constant at e.g. median or zero?

For example, the example from UCLA's ATS [site on NegBin regression](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/nbreg.htm):

```
require(foreign)
require(ggplot2)
require(MASS)
dat <- read.dta("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/dae/nb_data.dta")
dat <- within(dat, {
    prog <- factor(prog, levels = 1:3, labels = c("General", "Academic", "Vocational"))
    id <- factor(id)
})
summary(m1 <- glm.nb(daysabs ~ math + prog, data = dat))
```

The resulting coefficients are evaluated at the mean value of `daysabs`, which is 5.96. It find it more intuitive to evaluate the coefficients at median values.

Comment: Quantile regression would do what you're asking for. The R module Quantreg would likely work...   http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantreg/index.html

Comment: Could you clarify what "they are all evaluated at mean values" is trying to convey? What are "they"--data, models, link functions, ...? What does "evaluated" mean--defined at, measured, set to, ...?  "Mean values" of what sets of data or distributions?

Comment: As @whuber said, it is a bit uncertain exactly what you are asking for. In your first paragraph, you state, "Is there a way to evaluate coefficients holding the values of other variables constant at e.g. median or zero", which is a very different question from what you pose at the end of your post when you say, "The resulting coefficients are evaluated at the mean value of daysabs", where daysabs is your response.